# Approach to determining most likely integer factors of a noisy measurement?

Tags: optimization

I have a quantity which is estimated from a number of noisy measurements. I know that the real underlying value must be some integer multiple of two quantities, e.g. $M = I_1C_1 + I_2C_2$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are some known (from theory) values and $I_1,I_2$ are the unknown integer multiples.

I'm casting this as a least squares minimisation problem, minimising over $I_1,I_2$ but I'm unsure of what minimisation technique is appropriate here? Is there some standard approach to this type of problem? I can get extreme values for the unknown integers by doing $ceil(M/C_i)$, so could then check every possible integer combination within that range. There are typically many such combinations though, so this would not be very efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this paper should be relevant to your problem:

Arash  Hassibi  and  Stephen  Boyd: [*Integer Parameter Estimation in Linear Models with Applications to GPS*](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/int_est.pdf). IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing, Vol. 46, No. 11, November 1998

The authors state that the integer least-squares problem is NP-hard, but can be solved efficiently in many practical cases by the [LLL algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a GPS processing issue, so that reference is very relevant.